# What's wrong with my code for CS50 runoff problem?

Tags: c, cs50

> The goal is to mimic a ranked-choice voting system wherein the voters will vote for all the candidates an rank them based on their preference. For a candidate to win he must have more than 50% votes.
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> ./runoff Alice Bob Charlie
> Number of voters: 5
> Rank 1: Alice
> Rank 2: Charlie
> Rank 3: Bob
>
> Rank 1: Alice
> Rank 2: Charlie
> Rank 3: Bob
>
> Rank 1: Bob
> Rank 2: Charlie
> Rank 3: Alice
>
> Rank 1: Bob
> Rank 2: Charlie
> Rank 3: Alice
>
> Rank 1: Charlie
> Rank 2: Alice
> Rank 3: Bob
>
> Alice
> ```
>
> In this scenario Alice won because Alice and Bob were tied to win, but because the last voter preferred Charlie since and Charlie got the least number of votes, Charlie is then eliminated from the race. And since that voter preferred Alice over Bob, Alice then gets the vote so Alice wins the race.

My code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (!candidates[preferences[i][j]].eliminated)
            {
                candidates[preferences[i][j]].votes++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > (candidate_count * 0.5))
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    int min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            if (candidates[i].votes > min)
                min = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    return min;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes != min && !candidates[i].eliminated)
            return false;
    }
        return true;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidiates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min)
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
    }
    return;
}
```

I get these errors...

```
:) runoff.c exists
:) runoff compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote correctly sets first preference for first voter
:) vote correctly sets third preference for second voter
:) vote correctly sets all preferences for voter
:) tabulate counts votes when all candidates remain in election
:) tabulate counts votes when one candidate is eliminated
:) tabulate counts votes when multiple candidates are eliminated
:( print_winner prints name when someone has a majority
    print_winner did not print winner of election
:( print_winner returns true when someone has a majority
    print_winner did not print winner and then return true
:( print_winner returns false when nobody has a majority
    print_winner did not return false
:( print_winner returns false when leader has exactly 50% of vote
    print_winner did not return false
:) find_min returns minimum number of votes for candidate
:) find_min returns minimum when all candidates are tied
:) find_min ignores eliminated candidates
:) is_tie returns true when election is tied
:) is_tie returns false when election is not tied
:) is_tie returns false when only some of the candidates are tied
:) is_tie detects tie after some candidates have been eliminated
:) eliminate eliminates candidate in last place
:) eliminate eliminates multiple candidates in tie for last
:) eliminate eliminates candidates after some already eliminated
```

Comment: What are your thoughts about those four error messages? Have you done any debugging? Any thoughts/leads/ideas?

Comment: I've trying to debug it right now and see what's the problem. The error message states the error is in the print_winner function so I'm trying to look into that function maybe I have some kind of logic error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got it... `if (candidates[i].votes > (candidate_count * 0.5))` candidate_count here is wrong it should be `if (candidates[i].votes > (voter_count * 0.5))`